# Java toString in class

Tags: java

I am getting an error of cannot find symbol in my code posted below. I am trying to initalise a sedan using it's class and have the toString function right after but nothing is working for me. Please help

```
class cars {
    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;

    public String sedancClass(String initMake, String initModel, String initColor, int initYear, double initPrice) {
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        color = initColor;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        String name = "Sedan";
        String main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " " + year + " costs $" + price);
        return main;

    }





}

public class autoPark {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        cars sedan1;
        sedan1 = new sedanClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on what you wrote, sedancClass is a method, not a constructor, which means you should not call it with "new", and the expected return type is String, not cars.  You would write String sedan1 = sedanClass("Ford", "Model-1", "white", 2015, 20000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you provided, I think this is what you are trying to do

```java
class cars {
    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;

    // parametised constructor
    public cars (String initMake, String initModel, String initColor, int initYear, double initPrice) {
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        color = initColor;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String name = "Sedan";
        String main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " " + year + " costs $" + price);
        return main;
    }

}

public class autoPark {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        cars sedan1; // declaring cars object by name sedan1
        sedan1 = new cars("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000); // initialising sedan1 using cars constructor
        System.out.println(sedan1); // printing sedan1 for invoking toString() method
    }
}
```

### Why we use @Override annotation [source](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/override-annotation-in-java/)

Using @Override annotation while overriding a method is considered as a best practice for coding in java because of the following two advantages:

1. If programmer makes any mistake such as wrong method name, wrong parameter types while overriding, you would get a compile time error. As by using this annotation you instruct compiler that you are overriding this method. If you don’t use the annotation then the sub class method would behave as a new method (not the overriding method) in sub class.
2. It improves the readability of the code. So if you change the signature of overridden method then all the sub classes that overrides the particular method would throw a compilation error, which would eventually help you to change the signature in the sub classes. If you have lots of classes in your application then this annotation would really help you to identify the classes that require changes when you change the signature of a method.

Comment: Ok just a couple questions, what does @override do? When I try to add more classes inside the main cars class, it says invalid method declaration, return type required. I followed the same steps as you did in public cars with another public SUV(xx,xxx,xx) and it keeps giving errors.

Comment: I see, thank you for your responses. Just one more thing, when I make another class called SUV with your exact steps, why does it need a return type and how do I add a toString for that constructor?

Comment: I am sorry it is not very clear what you are saying. If you could show me the code I will be more helpful

Comment: https://controlc.com/e1201a3e theres a link to the code, I am trying to basically make more classes inside cars and more toString's

Comment: Always remember you cannot create more than one method with the same signature within a class. In your case, you create more than one `toString()` method which is causing a problem. To resolve this you should create separate classes for each of vehicle type and create a `toString()` method. [code](https://controlc.com/316aa422) .To improve the quality of code I will recommend you to do the same problem with inheritance in java.